# How to automatically adjust the size of a parent box in css?

Tags: html, css

How can I make "cols_img" boxes to be inside the "col2" box in the code below? I know that if I increase padding for "col2" it will work, but is there a way to automatically do this?

```css
html {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.col2 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.cols_img {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class=col2>
  <div class="cols_img"></div>  
 <div class="cols_img"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need clearing your floatting elements : https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: Definitely a dupe.

Comment: User **display:inline-block** for parent

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is use the `:after` on your `col2` class

```
.col2:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display: inline-block instead of float.

```
.cols_img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/97gq048L/